# how to add a new parameter to SqlParameter[ ] Collection?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

I want to use something similar like this:

```
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    SqlParameter[] dbParams = new SqlParameter[]
    {                        
        new SqlParameter("@PromptID", promptID)
    };

    if (scenarioID != 0)
        dbParams.Concat(new SqlParameter("@ScenarioID", scenarioID));
    //OR
    if (scenarioID != 0)
        dbParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@ScenarioID", scenarioID));
    }
}
```

I have searched for adding IEnumarable collection but it doesn't solve my problem. Should I create two collections and concat them? I think there must be an easy way to add an item. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear why you've got that `DataSet` at all, by the way...

Comment: use List<SqlParameter> dbParams and then you can do dbParams.Add(new SqlParemeter("@PromptID", promptID)

Comment: @EhsanUllah - It is generally recommended that you put answers to questions in an answer. Comments are not permanent and may be deleted, so they are generally reserved for questions about questions or tangential information.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use a list instead:

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@PromptID", promptID)
};
if (scenarioID != 0)
{
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ScenarioID", scenarioID));
}
```

If you *really* need an array at the end, you can always use:

```
var array = parameters.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@PromptID", promptID),       
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use List instead of array.

```
   List<SqlParameter> dbParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
```

and then you can do

```
   dbParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@PromptID", promptID);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum number of items (instanses of `SQLParameter` type) then following approach is ideal. Else you can go with `List<SqlParameter>` approach, which is briefed by peers.

```
 var dbParams = new SqlParameter[2];
 dbParams.SetValue(new SqlParameter("@PromptID", promptID),0);
 dbParams.SetValue(new SqlParameter("@ScenarioID", scenarioID), scenarioID != 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Other suggestion:

```
SqlParameter[] sqlPar = new SqlParameter[1];
sqlPar[0] = new SqlParameter("@System", "Teste");
```