# No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegisterUser", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);

SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword);
SqlParameter email = new SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
SqlParameter userType = new SqlParameter("@UserType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
userType.Value = "Student";
cmd.Parameters.Add(username);
cmd.Parameters.Add(password);
cmd.Parameters.Add(email);
cmd.Parameters.Add(userType);

con.Open();

int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //This is where it displays error message
if (ReturnCode == -1)
```

Any ideas?

Here is the error message

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 48:                     con.Open();
> Line 49: 
> Line 50:                     int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
> Line 51:                     if (ReturnCode == -1)
> Line 52:                     {
> ```
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Mubashir\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sit302GroupProject\Sit302GroupProject\Registration\Registration.aspx.cs    Line: 50
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.]
>        System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromValue(Type dataType, Object value, Boolean inferLen, Boolean streamAllowed) +2021139
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetMetaTypeOnly() +5287377
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc) +16
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters) +122
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc) +78
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1379
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
>        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +149
>        Sit302GroupProject.Registration.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Mubashir\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Sit302GroupProject\Sit302GroupProject\Registration\Registration.aspx.cs:50
>        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9552602
>        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
>        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>        System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>        System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>        System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
> ```

Here is the Stored Procedure

```
CREATE proc spRegisterUser
@Username nvarchar(100),
@Password nvarchar(200),
@Email  nvarchar(200),
@UserType  nvarchar(200),
as 
Begin 
Declare @Count int
Declare @ReturnCode int

Select @Count = COUNT(UserName)
from tblUsers where UserName = @UserName
If @COunt > 0
Begin 
Set @Return = -1
End
Else
Begin
Set @ReturnCode = 1
Insert into tblUsers values
(@UserName, @Password, @Email, @UserType)
End
Select @ReturnCode as ReturnValue
End
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16714573/194717

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are passing `txtPassword` which is an object of TextBox, thus you are getting exception.

Problem is in line

```
SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword);
```

So change your code to

```
SqlParameter password = new SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This a function for passing SQL parameter to stored procedure:

```
public static SqlParameter Parameter( SqlDbType dbtype,  string ParameterName, string Value)
{
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = ParameterName;
        param.SqlDbType = dbtype;
        param.SqlValue = Value;
        return param;
        // cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
}
```

You can use this the function like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Name");
cmd.Parameter.Add(Parameter(SqlDbType.DateTime,"@Parameter",DateTimepicker.Text));
```

**OR**

```
SqlParameter[] parameters =
{
    new SqlParameter("@Task", "insert"),
    new SqlParameter("@Name", clsPluginHelper.DbNullIfNullOrEmpty(txtinstalName.Text)),
    new SqlParameter("@Descp", clsPluginHelper.DbNullIfNullOrEmpty(txtInstDescp.Text)),
    clsPluginHelper.Parameter(SqlDbType.DateTime, "@StartDate",dtpInstStartDate.Text),
    clsPluginHelper.Parameter(SqlDbType.DateTime, "@EndDate",dtpInstalEndDate.Text)
};
```