# ERROR: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a receipttextbox field I am trying to have user's put in some value such as RE0001234 and query the database then return the value to a label.  Right now as it stands if I put in my own value within the code in my query it returns the result to the label as expected but when asking for user input I get this error:  No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

```
protected void receiptbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string getReceipt = receiptbox.Text;

}
protected void sealresultquery_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{

}
protected void searchbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    sealresult.Text = "";
    receiptbox.Text = "";
    string getReceipt = receiptbox.Text;
    string connString = @"Data Source=SQL;Initial Catalog=XYZDATABASE;User ID=ADMIN;Password=*********";
    string query = "Select seal1 from dbo.RECEIPTHEADER where receipt = @getReceipt";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@getReceipt, receiptbox));


    using (conn)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                sealresult.Text += reader[0].ToString();

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            querystatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestions as to what I am missing, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note my receipttexbox is: protected void receiptbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { string getReceipt = receiptbox.Text;

Comment: Do you mean to pass receiptbox.text to the parameter? You are passing the entire object, no?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212706/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-web-ui-webcontrols-textbox-to-a-known/19212759

Comment: I have managed to get no errors, however my value returns nothing now.  Here is the updated code, I think I am missing something in receiptbox code behind.

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/grant/vmqa9xjvshaaayv4xx9aow33yzc6a7br/accept

Comment: I placed the code above in ghostbin, hopefully someone could help me figure this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>When you called the Parameters.Add() method, you were using the [Add(String,Object) overload, which has been marked as obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx).</strike>  I believe the value of the parameter could not be determined, so it was as if you were trying to find a receipt without an ID.

Take a look at the other [methods of the SqlParameterCollection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) to see what parameters they take.  The second value of the Add() method is always the database type and never the value.

Try this:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@getReceipt, SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = receiptbox.Text;
```

or this (the same but shorter):

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@getReceipt", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = receiptbox.Text;
```

You're also setting the value from the form to be empty with `receiptbox.Text = ""`, so that should be removed.  The line above and below this line don't add any value to the solution either.

Comment: The Add-Method is used with Parameter Of Type SqlParameter, so this can't be the problem.

Comment: Ah, correct.  I think that I had two different questions opened when I wrote that first paragraph, but the rest is valid.  The value wasn't being passed.

Comment: The Value is passed, but the ParameterName didn't fit `@getReceipt` isn't `"@getReceipt"`.

Comment: This was the answer... Worked like a charm!  Thank very very much @Nikolaus!  Have another question I will be posting very soon as well about an update query.

Comment: I had written this in my answer below ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`.Text` attribute missing end of the receiptbox control, change `comm.Parameters.Add(...` line with this

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@getReceipt", receiptbox.Text));
```

and move `receiptbox.Text = "";` line to end of using, because it clears the input before using.

OR

change order of lines like this.

```
string getReceipt = receiptbox.Text;
receiptbox.Text = "";
```

and use `getReceipt`   instead of `receiptbox.Text`

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@getReceipt", getReceipt));
```

Comment: Thank you, That did work in removing the error, but now I do not have a return value in sealresult.Text return label,  I did have it before when i placed the value in the query, but now I get no error nor any result.  Suggestion?

Comment: what is the control type of receiptbox? And can you write possible receiptbox value and table values?

Comment: https://ghostbin.com/paste/grant/vmqa9xjvshaaayv4xx9aow33yzc6a7br/accept

Comment: I have added the code above in ghost bin that controls the receiptbox

Comment: did you debug the code? the pointer run into while? did you manually run select query with your parameter? what is the result?

Comment: I have not ran the debug.  I did run the code with query with an actual value where @receipt is and my webform label searchresult.  So I know my program works and that the connection is valid because I got the data back when I ask for a unique value in the query.  It seems to break when I place a text into receiptbox.   I get no more errors though so something is working, but not returning the value to my searchresult label.  Did I mention that receiptbox will be taking values such as: RE00007878.  Could this be my problem?

Comment: I updated my answer, I debug it and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting things in wrong order:

```
receiptbox.Text = "";
string getReceipt = receiptbox.Text;
```

Try:

```
string getReceipt = receiptbox.Text;
receiptbox.Text = "";
```

Update:
If you do it like that, then the Paramname is the Text of the TextBox:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@getReceipt, receiptbox.Text));
```

Try this in addition to the other answers:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@getReceipt", receiptbox.Text));
```

Comment: Hey@Nikolaus, I tried that but it did not work as well.

Comment: I may be missing a class.. because I have it exactly like this but my Parameters is not blue in my code like others are.  This is what I am using, is it that I am missing a class? 'using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;'

Comment: You can also try: `comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"@getReceipt", receiptbox.Text);`

Comment: @vk_devman This should be enough. Maybe I have formatted false, because I'm answering/commenting from my mobile phone.